# how do i run ubuntu after unzipping download on usb drive

Tags: usb, usb-drive

I went to the penlinux download site and did not see the screen as shown on the ubuntu site , so I wen to the down load page on ubuntu downloaded the desktop in a zip file to a usb stick drive unzipped the file , now how do I run ubuntu from this stick drive

Comment: Use unetbootin to create bootalbe version. It is the easiest way.

Answer (score 1):

What you downloaded is an ISO file, and not a ZIP file.  The reason you see it as a ZIP file, because you have nothing associated with ISO file.  You have to actually create the bootable USB using the ISO file, and jut unzipping it to it.  When you run the Universal USB Installer, you have to browse for the ISO file, and then click on Create, as shown in the image below:

[image]

Once the USB gets created, you need to reboot you system, go into the BIOS, and change the boot order to boot from USB.